# Qt: setScreenRect = segfault

Tags: c++, qt

Basically I need something to draw on it,
that is simple to use with designer (for example inherit from QWidget and override of paintEvent require some efforts to use it in Qt designer).

So I add QGraphicsView to .ui file and write such code in button method:

```
QGraphicsScene *scene = ui->graphicsView->scene();    
const QRectF scene_r = ui->graphicsView->sceneRect();
//here I see that scene_r == {0, 0, 0, 0};
```

then I add such code:

```
const QSize draw_size = ui->graphicsView->size();
//draw_size == {100, 100}
scene->setSceneRect(QRectF(0, 0, draw_size.width(), draw_size.height()));
```

and got segfault on line `scene->setSceneRect` what is going on here?

Actually I want right such code:

```
//scene size == draw_size
QPixmap pix(draw_size.width(), draw_size.height());
//fill pix with external program
scene->addPixmap(map_pix);
```

is it possible?

I never before work with QGraphicsView.

Comment: And `scene` is not a null pointer?

Comment: Yes, `scene` is `nullptr`, thanks, I never think dig into this way, because of what sense to create `QGraphicsView` without scene.

Comment: It is always a good idea to have an object before you use it ;)

Comment: "what sense to create QGraphicsView without scene" They are separate: you might have many scenes, and many views, and can have many views per scene. A scene is not owned by a view. So it's on you to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get a segfault is because you haven't set any scene for the view, hence the scene() will return a null pointer.

```
QGraphicsScene scene;
QGraphicsView view(&scene);
view.show();
```

Alternative is to create the view without a scene then add it later:

```
void    setScene(QGraphicsScene *scene)
```

Reference:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html